# Why does this simple MSpec test return inconclusive?

Tags: integration-testing, mspec, fakeiteasy

I am using Mspec with FakeItEasy and I keep getting inconclusive test results. I tried commenting out my fake setup code and even the actual invocation of the method under test. I'm also unable to debug the test. I also just tried a simple test like this:

```
private Then it_should_be_true = () => true.ShouldBeTrue();
```

What is the cause of inconclusive tests?

[image]

```
[Tags("IntegrationTest")]
[Subject(typeof(AuthManager))]
public class When_a_login_is_performed_using_valid_credentials
{
    protected static string MemberUsername;
    protected static string MemberPassword;
    protected static SignInResponse Response;

    private Given context = () =>
    {
        MemberUsername = "User1";
        MemberPassword = "Pass1";
    };

    private When test = () =>
    {
        Response = AuthManager.Current.SignIn(MemberUsername, MemberPassword);
    };

    private Then It_should_return_a_successful_response = () => Response.Success.ShouldBeTrue();
    private Then It_should_not_contain_any_reported_errors = () => Response.Errors.ShouldBeEmpty();
    private Then It_should_have_an_Id_populated = () => Response.Id.ShouldNotBeEmpty();
}
```

I wrapped It to become Then to match BDD syntax using the below code. It has always worked in the past.

```
using Machine.Specifications;

namespace Testing.MachineSpecifications
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Given
    /// </summary>
    [SetupDelegate]
    public delegate void Given();

    /// <summary>
    /// When
    /// </summary>
    [ActDelegate]
    public delegate void When();

    /// <summary>
    /// Then
    /// </summary>
    [AssertDelegate]
    public delegate void Then();
}
```

Comment: I'm not a Machine.Specifications expert, so I'll approach this from another direction first. In what way does this use FakeItEasy? If you remove FakeItEasy from the project altogether does anything change? Have you been able to run Machine.Specifications tests in the past?

Comment: Yes I have other Mspec tests in other libraries that have run successfully. Just mentioned FakeItEasy for completeness. Just wondering if there is a common scenario that causes these kind of test results?

Comment: Ah, I don't have light to shed, unfortunately. FakeItEasy actually uses Machine.Specifications for its acceptance tests, so the two are not completely incompatible. Sorry.

Comment: Can you provide the entire class? I am suspicious that something might be wrong with this class's visibility.

Comment: Also, can you comment on the test runner you're using... seems to be some trouble with ReSharper in the past. https://github.com/machine/machine.specifications.runner.resharper/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+inconclusive

Comment: Post the whole class that contains your assertion.  Also, I'm not sure where `Then` comes from, MSpec uses `It`.

Comment: I am using the latest MSpec runner extension installed through the Resharper Extension Manager https://github.com/machine/machine.specifications.runner.resharper and I wrapped `Because` and `It` in `When` and `Then` to match BDD style syntax. I have used that successfully in the past without issues.

Comment: I also tried just using the normal `Establish/Because/It` delegates instead of my wrappers and that also didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [machine.specifications.runner.resharper](https://github.com/machine/machine.specifications.runner.resharper) runner was one version behind ReSharper. In the future, it would be good to wait on upgrading ReSharper until the runner has time to catch up with compatibility.